# Accessing json data returned from web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have a web method that is returning this json data:

```
{
   "TotalItems":25,
   "Assets":
       [
           {"Id":"49c1fc23-edab-4087-bf3b-884b16399e4b"},
           {"Id":"5f8f5aaa-dcfa-4a3f-ae21-b7a9683551e5"},
           {"Id":"f589f567-c4d0-49e8-acf4-d3dcd1813b4d"},
           {"Id":"b5678b13-1d07-4be5-9c70-02f8475de771"}
       ]
}
```

Here's my ajax call and the method I call when the data returns.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Services.asmx/GetAssets",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results) {

        alert(results["d"]);   // alerts json above
        alert(results.d);      // alerts json above

        // all of these alert "undefined"
        alert(results["d"]["TotalItems"]);
        alert(results["d"].TotalItems);
        alert(results.d["TotalItems"]);
        alert(results.d.TotalItems);
    }
});
```

How can I access the data inside the json result?

Comment: i think the `results.d` is a string and you should use `JSON.parse(results.d)` before accessing any properties.

Comment: what about `results.TotalItems`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use JSON.parse in order to turn the returned JSON into an actual javascript object.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(results.d);
parsed.TotalItems //Allow access of total items variable from JSON
```

You can read more about this at http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

i think the `results.d` is a string and you should use `JSON.parse(results.d)` before accessing any properties.